# 11 entre 2 me devuelve 5.0 en vez de 5.5

Tags: java

Entero dividido entre entero no me devuelve decimal.
Por ejemplo **11/2 me da 5.0 en vez de 5.5** ¿Qué sucede?

```
import java.util.*;
public class Division {

static double resultado;
static int num1=11;
static int num2=2;

public static void main(String[] args) {
resultado=num1/num2; /*Devuelve 5.0 en vez de 5.5*/
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

eso es debido a que las variables num1 y num2 son int, lo ideal es que si el resultado es double, las variables num1 y num2 también lo sean. Quedaría así:

```java
import java.util.*;
public class Division {

static double resultado;
static double num1=11;
static double num2=2;

public static void main(String[] args) {
resultado=num1/num2; /*Devuelve 5.0 en vez de 5.5*/
}
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda, un saludo.

Comment: Es recomendable que al instanciar variables de tipo `double` o `float`se indique el tipo con el sufijo `D` o `F`. Ejem: `double num1 = 11.0D` o `float num2 = 2.0F`

Answer (score 2):

La división de dos enteros da como resultado un entero

```
static double resultado;
static double num1 = 11.0;
static double num2 = 2.0;
resultado = num1 / num2; //5.5
```

Answer (score 2):

> > 11 entre 2 me devuelve 5.0 en vez de 5.5

Te da como resultado `5.0`, porqué el compilador asume que esta expresión:

```
num1/num2
```

Será de tipo `int` y por ende, habrá pérdida de datos y por esa razón, la variable `resultado` tendrá el número `5.0`.

Una posible solución (si te interesa que las variables `num1` y `num2` sean de tipo `int`) es realizar una conversión explicita, es decir, le indicaremos al compilador que el resultado de la expresión `num1/num2` será de **TIPO DOUBLE**.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    resultado= (double)num1/num2;
    System.out.println(resultado);
    //Resultado por pantalla: 5.5
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Como dicen los demás debes poner tus variables en **`DOUBLE`**, así tu código funcionará; cambia tu código por eso:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Division {

static double resultado;
static double num1=11;
static double num2=2;

public static void main(String[] args) {
resultado=num1/num2; /*Devuelve 5.0 en vez de 5.5 ahora si te devolverá 5.5*/
 }
}
```